# ODBC source SQL Server unable to connect to local Sql express 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019, odbc

On My Win10 I'm trying to connect to my local Sql Server Express via ODBC. I must the ODBC driver "SQL Server". I create the connection via ODBC sources.
I Receive an error prompt. I've Translated the output:
SQLState: "08001"
SQL Server-Error: 18
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL-Securityerror.

If i test another ODBC driver eg. "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" or "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" I can connect.

Anyone know if it is possible to connect to Express 2019 with odbc driver "SQL Server"?

Comment: Why do you need to use the old SQL Server driver that ships with Windows? It's been deprecated for over 15 years and not recommended.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you on?  The SQL Server ODBC driver and SQLOLEDB driver have recently been updated to support TLS 1.2.  I'm on 20H2 and I can connect using TLS 1.2.